# Microsoft Skype quit permanently for linux? Skype is not working on Ubuntu 12.10, 13.04, 13.10

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, 13.10, skype, voip

Except this last Skype, https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B615bolUUtVBMmlPem1DWHlwMmM/edit?pli=1

There is no other Skype working in Ubuntu. Where to get Skype for 13.10 - 64-bit?

```
root@sun-M14xR2:~/Downloads# dpkg -i skype-
skype-4.2.0.11/                           skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb  
root@sun-M14xR2:~/Downloads# dpkg -i skype-
skype-4.2.0.11/                           skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb  
root@sun-M14xR2:~/Downloads# dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package skype.
(Reading database ... 231637 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking skype (from skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
 skype depends on libasound2 (>= 1.0.23); however:
  Package libasound2:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype
```

EDIT: the default download .deb file is never working

```
root@sun-M14xR2:~/Downloads# skype 
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
root@sun-M14xR2:~/Downloads# ldd /usr/bin/skype 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7754000)
    libasound.so.2 => not found
    libXv.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1 (0xf5943000)
    libXss.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1 (0xf593e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf5935000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf5930000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf57f8000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf57e6000)
    libQtDBus.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtDBus.so.4 (0xf5766000)
    libQtWebKit.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4 (0xf402d000)
    libQtXml.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtXml.so.4 (0xf3fed000)
    libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0xf351d000)
    libQtNetwork.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0xf33da000)
    libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0xf30f7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf30dc000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf2ff0000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf2fc4000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf2fa7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf2dfc000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7755000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf2dd9000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0xf2d8d000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0xf2cdf000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xf2cd5000)
    libgstapp-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstapp-0.10.so.0 (0xf2cc7000)
    libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 (0xf2cb5000)
    libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 (0xf2c93000)
    libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 (0xf2c75000)
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0xf2c14000)
    libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0xf2b2c000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xf2adc000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf29e0000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xf29a8000)
    libaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2 (0xf298f000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xf2965000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf294c000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf28b2000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0xf28a9000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0xf288f000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0xf287f000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf287b000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf2874000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0xf27e5000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xf27df000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0xf2690000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xf2689000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xf2649000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf2621000)
    libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0xf25c3000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xf25bd000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0xf2597000)
root@sun-M14xR2:~/Downloads# apt-get install libasound
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libasound
root@sun-M14xR2:~/Downloads# apt-get install libasound2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libasound2 is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.23)
              Recommends: sni-qt:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get install libasound2:i386`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. `dpkg` is just complaining about a missing dependency. That's easy to fix, though.

After installing Skype using

```
sudo dpkg -i  skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
```

tell your system to install the missing dependencies using

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

That should install the `libasound2:i386` package and configure your Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix broken dependancies with `sudo apt-get -f install` next update with `sudo apt-get update` and the try the `dpkg` command again